# Identity Server 3 - Silent sign-in / sign in without login page. Including single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver3

I have come across a number of articles that discuss a similar matter but I cannot find a definitive answer.

My company would like to begin using Identity Server 3, however one of the requirements is to be able to authenticate an external user without them having to manually enter their credentials.

This must be capable of providing single sign on capabilities also as we have 3 different systems and our users should only have to sign in once.

Essentially, the external user has their own CRM.

- The CRM holds their username and password for our software.
- They then click a button in their CRM to launch our application
- This redirects them to our website with a payload containing their credentials
- We call a web service to authenticate the user

It is fundamental that we do not change this process for our partners.

Can I implement a custom service provider to provide the authentication or is there some other way of achieving this? If so, could you point me in the right direction for how this can be done?

Many thanks

Craig

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you'd create a mechanism for their CRM to get a token at the time the client logs into their site and then have them send that token via url to your callback page. This would use the machine-to-machine type grant, or the client-credentials flow. Then that page could validate the token and log the user in. There would have to be some sort of unique identifier between the two systems like email or something. Just an idea.